# OpenZeppelin docs - importing another contract

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin

gm, I'm a little confused by the following sample code for importing a contract, see Box imports Auth.

I'm not sure whether the example is supposed to be deployable, or if it's just an example and I'm not supposed to question it too much.

See code, below.

- If I were to deploy Box, then Auth would not be deployed, so I'd presumably need to deploy Auth first, but this throws up the question of addressing the exact instance of Auth from Box.
- So perhaps the deployment system picks-up the import and deploys Auth first, gets its address and then rewires the import.
- But if that's the case, then what value will it use for the `deployer` argument?!

#### Excerpt

Source: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/learn/developing-smart-contracts?pref=hardhat#adding-more-contracts

```
// contracts/access-control/Auth.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Auth {
    address private _administrator;

    constructor(address deployer) {
        // Make the deployer of the contract the administrator
        _administrator = deployer;
    }

    function isAdministrator(address user) public view returns (bool) {
        return user == _administrator;
    }
}
```

To use this contract from Box we use an import statement, referring to Auth by its relative path:

```
// contracts/Box.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

// Import Auth from the access-control subdirectory
import "./access-control/Auth.sol";

contract Box {
    uint256 private _value;
    Auth private _auth;

    event ValueChanged(uint256 value);

    constructor() {
        _auth = new Auth(msg.sender);
    }

    function store(uint256 value) public {
        // Require that the caller is registered as an administrator in Auth
        require(_auth.isAdministrator(msg.sender), "Unauthorized");

        _value = value;
        emit ValueChanged(value);
    }

    function retrieve() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Their doc on upgrading smart contracts is really confusing, but then I see they explain how it works further down the page. Putting this critical info at the bottom, betrays how they view their readers. They see me as not knowledgable enough to become confused, if that makes sense. They don't expect me to be smart enough to have spotted (and become confused by) the gaps. I hate this kind of documentation. They must explain everything in detail as it happens and a smart doc writer will anticipate questions and head them off.